# the notation $d^2y$ has nothing to do with "squared"?

Tags: calculus

I have looked up lots of posts asking about why it's $d^2/dx^2$ and how $dx$ itself is a variable, but I can't find answers explaining how the notation, specifically "$d^2y$" is derived apart from $dx^2$.

I am confused if $d^2y$ means that $d$ is squared or it merely is an operator just like $d/dx$ itself is (so it has nothing to do with being "squared"). I think the latter explanation is right but I haven't seen any clear explanation how it's derived that way.

Comment: please use matjax

Comment: The first should be "derivating twice with respect of the variable $x$", no idea what "d^2*y" should be.

Comment: @Peter I wanted to express the second derivative "d2y/dx2" and expressed that 2 in d2y as ^2 since it's written as squared d, but anyway sorry for the confusion

Comment: @potato_man I will edit my post accordingly after learning how to use matjax thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Consider the expression $\frac{dy}{dx} =$ the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$.  Now consider the following expression:$$\frac{d\left[\frac{dy}{dx}\right]}{dx} =$$ the derivative of the derivative of $y$ with respect to x, with respect to $x$ (i.e. the second derivative).  For notational convenience (and no other significance), this is commonly written as $$\frac{d^2 \,y}{dx^2}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it has nothing to do with the squaring of anything. It is basically interpreted as the second derivative of the evaluated function.

A common mistake for beginners to calculus.

Comment: So it's just a notation which can be confused with the "squared" symbol! Thank you so much!:)

Comment: Glad to have cleared the misconception. I see you are new to calculus. Well, good luck!

Answer (score 6):

$dy/dx$ is not a ratio of two quantities—$dy$ and $dx$. However, sometimes we can 'pretend' that it is. The notation for the second derivative comes from
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=\frac{d^2y}{(dx)^2} \, .
$$
Because mathematicians are lazy, we often omit the parentheses on the bottom and write
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} \, .
$$
But to reiterate, this is *just* notation. The fact that we 'multiply' the $d$'s together to obtain this notation does not mean that $dy$  and $dx$ are independent quantities, and nor does it mean that $dx$ is the product of two variables $d$ and $x$.